# How to get a JavaScript file from Blogger blog

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have created a page on Blogger and put the javascript codes inside it, and I want to bring this code to another blog via **idBlog** or the link ...

I created this code so that it fetches everything inside the class **myscript** that is found in the blog pages with idBlog **XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX** , but it did not work for me :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var idBlog= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$(function(){"use strict";$.ajax({dataType:"json",url:"https://www.blogger.com/feeds/"+idBlog+"/pages/default?alt=json-in-script",method:"GET",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){var t;for(t=0;t<e.feed.entry.length;t+=1){var n=$(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t);if(0===t&&!$("body").hasClass("error_page")){for(var o=n.find("li"),d=[],a=0;a<o.length;a+=1)d.push($(o[a]).text());var r,i=window.location.hostname.toLowerCase(),f=window.location.href.toLowerCase(),s=d.length-1;for(r=0;r<d.length;r+=1){if(-1!=i.indexOf(d[r])){var l=$(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t).find("script"),p=$(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t).find("style");$("head").append(p),$("head").append(l);break}r==s&&-1==f.indexOf("post-preview")&&-1==f.indexOf("www.blogger")&&-1==f.indexOf("b/layout-preview")&&-1==f.indexOf("b/preview")&&-1==f.indexOf("translate.google")&&-1==f.indexOf("webcache.googleusercontent")&&-1==f.indexOf("template-editor")&&$("html").html(n.find( ".myscript" ).html())}}if(1===t){p=$(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t).find("style");$("head").append(p)}}}})});});
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do and what your error is.

Comment: I am trying to import class content to blogger blog, and this class is found in another blog via idblog